# Why do lots of dashes appear when I perform this split?

Tags: python, text-files

When I try to perform `split_2` lots of dashes appear in the resulting split, with more appearing each time [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdwSO.png) Does anyone know why this is?

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")
newlines = list()

def appendA():

 with open('cropdatabase.txt', 'r') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()

  for line in lines:
    if crop in line:
        index = lines.index(line)
        line = str(line)
        split_2 = line.split(' ')
        split_2.append(quantity + '  ')
        split_2 = str(split_2)
        print(split_2)
        newlines = lines
        newlines[index] = split_2


def appendB():

 file = open('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+')
 file.write('\n')
 file.write(crop + ' ')
 file.write(quantity + ' ')

if crop in open('cropdatabase.txt').read():
 appendA()
else:
 appendB()
```

Comment: I get IndentationError on a number of lines. Check if this is the actual code you are using.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation

Comment: @superato The indentation is still off. It wouldn't run if I tried but maybe it looks different on your end. Are you using python 2 or python 3?  Some pointers: you open files everal times using the same variable name `file`. That's causing some weird behvaiour. Also, you never do anything with `file` in the last `with open()`. Check out other questions and the python docs to see how reading and writing files via `with open` are supposed to look.

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: It definitely now has the  indentation that I'm using.

Comment: @superato ok. The idea in python is that every line should use the same number of spaces for indentation - typically 4. If you look at `for line in lines: if crop in line: index = lines.index(line)`, you have 2 spaces, 2 spaces but then 4 spaces. In the last `with open()` you have 1 space, then 3 spaces of indentation. Just use 4 spaces everywhere.

Comment: Any idea why the \ appear?

Comment: @superato Yes, because of some of the things I mentioned in my first comment (although it was badly written): *"Some pointers: you open files several times using the same variable name `file`. That's causing some weird behaviour. Also, you never do anything with file in the last `with open()`. Check out other questions and the python docs to see how reading and writing files via `with open()` are supposed to look"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not "dashes": they are "backslashes" which in Python is the escape character.  This is a dash: -

There are quite a few things in your code which could do with improvement. For example, you read the file twice unnecessarily.  You don't close the file properly except where you open it in the `with` statement.  Using `index` to find the line number is very inefficient: it requires iterating through the whole file for each new line - for no good reason.  You also don't write out the changes you make in `newlines`.

But the specific problem you mention, in which you are seeing a lot of escape characters in your file, is caused when you convert the list returned by `split` into a string using `str`.  This does not give you the format you want in your file. In particular it returns the `repr` of the contained strings which requires all special characters to be escaped.

Try this example to help you understand:

```
s = 'abc'
for i in range(5):
    s = [s]
    s = str(s)
    print(s)
```

Use `' '.join` instead.  Note the space there inside the quotes.

Here's new code with some of the other problems also sorted out:

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")

with open('cropdatabase.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
# At this point the file has been closed

# Don't use the index method to find the line number - just count up
# as you go.
for index,line in enumerate(lines):
    if crop in line:
        split_2 = line.split(' ')
        split_2.append(quantity)
        split_2 = ' '.join(split_2)
        print(split_2)
        lines[index] = split_2
        # You need to write out the file here if you want it to change
        break
else:
 with open('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:
     file.write('\n')
     file.write(crop + ' ')
     file.write(quantity + ' ')
```

Finally, it's not clear from this code why you split the line at all?  Why not just append the quantity?

Answer (score 1):

Here is with the proper indenting I think. Even with your revised code up top I think you aren't indenting the code you want in your functions properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")
newlines = list()

def appendA():
    with open('cropdatabase.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
           if crop in line:
               index = lines.index(line)
               line = str(line)
               split_2 = line.split(' ')
               split_2.append(quantity + '  ')
               split_2 = str(split_2)
               print(split_2)
               newlines = lines
               newlines[index] = split_2
    file.close()

def appendB():
    file = open('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+')
    file.write('\n' + crop + ' ' + quantity)
    file.close()

with open('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:
    if crop in open('cropdatabase.txt').read():
        appendA()
    else:
        appendB()
```

Comment: You have 8 spaces of indentation in `def appendA():` and then 3 further down and then 4. It should be 4 everywhere.

Comment: No problem. Welcome aboard :)